# How do I draw curve crossing one edge of a tree (using tikz-qtree)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, tikz-qtree

I am using `tikz-qtree`, and I'd like to draw a curve separating a set of nodes from the rest of the tree. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw,
                top color=white,bottom color=yellow!80,
                very thin},
                level distance=1.5cm,
                sibling distance=0.6cm]
  \Tree[.{$+$}
           [.{$*$}
               [.{$\cos$}
                   [.{$a$} ] ]
               [.{$2$} ] ]
               [.{$y$} ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces this (sorry, I don't know yet how exactly to upload pictures to tex.stackexchange, so this ended up a bit small):

[image]

Now, I'd like to draw a (dotted) curve that crosses one edge (for example, the edge from `*` to `cos`) -- splitting the set of nodes in two (`cos` and `a` and all the others).

I know I can use the `fit` library to draw an ellipsis around the nodes, but I'd like
an open line instead (more like a circumference arc, or a bezier curve).

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use TikZ `\node`s with names (See Section **4 Embedding TikZ nodes** of the `tikz-qtree` documentation) and then draw the dotted line using any valid `TikZ` method. An example with a straight line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw,
                top color=white,bottom color=yellow!80,
                very thin},
                level distance=1.5cm,
                sibling distance=0.6cm]
  \Tree[.{$+$}
           [.\node(ast){$*$};
               [.\node(cos){$\cos$};
                   [.{$a$} ] ]
               [.{$2$} ] ]
               [.{$y$} ] ]
\path[draw,dotted] ( $ (ast) + (-1,0) $) -- ++(-55:2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And an example with a curve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw,
                top color=white,bottom color=yellow!80,
                very thin},
                level distance=1.5cm,
                sibling distance=0.6cm]
  \Tree[.{$+$}
           [.\node(ast){$*$};
               [.\node(cos){$\cos$};
                   [.{$a$} ] ]
               [.{$2$} ] ]
               [.{$y$} ] ]
\path[draw,dotted] ( $ (ast) + (-1,0) $) to[out=230,in=23] ++(-58:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to connect nodes. I want the dotted curve to cross the edge between `*` and `cos`, but not connect nodes.

Comment: @Jay please see my updated answer. Is something like that what you want?

Comment: Hm, yes! Not a curve, but it's just fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Jay I just added an example with a curve.

Comment: Great! 8-)  Even better! Thanks a lot!